# Is it impossible to use custom view in delete action ( swipe button ) on UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiswipeactionsconfiguration

Currently, I want to use custom view on swiping delete action like this
[My custom view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAfaV.png)

Is it impossible to do that?

For now,I use function `trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt` for custom icon image and title but I have no idea how to round corner of its background.

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible or not, but you can create custom views for delete actions with various CocoaPods, such as [this one](https://cocoapods.org/pods/SwipeCellKit).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about custom views but there is a library called 'SWTableViewCell', it gives default icon for edit, delete, apply, edit.
You can find similar libraries too.